# ND4J getRows not working on a vector

Tags: java, nd4j

Using **N4DJ** in **java nd4j-native-platform** version **0.9.1**

I am trying to create a subset of an array by only selecting certain rows. I do this using the *getRows* method.

This works fine for matrices, however when my matrix comprises of a single row vector I get an incorrect result, see below example showing how calling method 
*getRow(int i)* works fine compared to *getRows(int...rows)*:

```
    final INDArray singleRowArray = Nd4j.create(new double[]{1,2,3,4},new int[]{1,4});
    System.out.println(singleRowArray);  //Output: [1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00]

    final INDArray getSingleRowArray = singleRowArray.getRow(0);
    System.out.println(getSingleRowArray); //Output: [1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00] as expected

    final INDArray getSingleRowArrayFromGetRowsSingle = singleRowArray.getRows(0);
    System.out.println(getSingleRowArrayFromGetRowsSingle); //Output: [1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00] expected the same as above
```

Current work around is to check whether the matrix is in fact a single vector and calling the *getRow* instead of the *getRows* method.

Is this a known issue for N4DJ or am I misunderstanding something?

Note that a similar issue is encountered for column vectors.

Comment: your code works fine for me. I am using version 1.0.0-alpha. Both answers are same